# Invariant subspaces of a direct sum of two nonisomorphic irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

I am totally stuck at this problem.... I can show that $P_1(U)$ must be $V_1$ or $0$ and $P_2(U)$ must be $V_2$ or $0$.

The problem is that what contradiction can I get when $P_1(U)=V_1$ and $P_2(U)=V_2$? I tried everything including Schur's lemma but have only failed and it is unbearably frustrating.....

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't assume that $U$ is irreducible, and merely assume that $U$ is neither $\{0\}$ nor all of $V_1 \oplus V_2$, then:

Let $U' \subseteq U$ be an irreducible subrepresentation. Then if $P_1(U') = V_1$, then by Schur's lemma, you have $U' \simeq V_1$. Similarly $P_2(U') = V_2$ implies $U' \simeq V_2$. Since $V_1$ and $V_2$ are nonisomorphic by assumption, you can't have both happen simultaneously.

Then by linear algebra with $U' \neq \{0\}$, it follows that $U' = V_1$ or $U' = V_2$. Say $U' = V_i$, and let $j \neq i$ with $\{i, j\} = \{1, 2\}$.

Then use the fact that $U/U' \subseteq (V_1 \oplus V_2)/V_i \simeq V_j$ to conclude that $U/U' =\{0\}$ and therefore $U = U'$.

Comment: Oh......I was so stupid....How can I then use this (a) to show that the only nontrivial subspaces of the direct sum are $V_1$ and $V_2$?

Comment: I know that a nonzero invariant subspace of a finite dimensional representation space has a nonzero irreducible invariant subspace.

Comment: From here it's just linear algebra. The combined criteria $P_1(U) = 0$ and $P_2(U) = V_2$ imply that $U = V_2$.

Comment: No, I do not assume irreducibility. I have to show that any nontrivial invariant subspace of the direct sum is either $V_1$ or $V_2$.

Comment: Oh yeah that's a subtlety.

Comment: @Keith check my edit.

Comment: Wow....so much thank...

Comment: Just one last check:  $U/U'$ is still an invariant subspace, so that the irreducibility of $V_j$ works. Right?

Comment: yes. It should be easy to verify that $U/U'$ is closed under the action of the group or lie algebra.